# Moving big mysql database to different server

Tags: mysql, server, bigdata

My database is nearly 10GB in size (12 tables roughly equal in size).

What is the proper way of moving this kind of data to a different server?

My thoughts are, breaking down each table into several files each containing cca 100 000 rows of given table. Then on the new machine loop through all files.

Please let there be a more efficient way, this sounds exhausting.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-can-i-move-a-database-from-one-server-to-another

Answer (score 0):

You can export database **tar.gz** format. When you export database must be

extend execute time.

i also export 3GB database in tar.gz format size 400MB.